# How to get other process's environment variable using c#

Tags: c#, .net, process, environment-variables

I have an **elevated process** and I'm trying to extract an environment variable from another process using C#. I know that the variable exists by using Process Explorer.

I can get the process environment variables like the following:

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("someprocess").First();
string value = process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["var_name"];
```

But **[StartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Diagnostics.Process.StartInfo);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) only returns a subset of the process env variables, passed to `process.Start()`**.

How can I get environment variables that have bee set during process run time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not well documented, but [`ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables(v=vs.110).aspx) does not return the environment of a specific process.

If you look at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessStartInfo.cs,5611ad13d0b7376e), you will see that under the hood the [`GetEnvironmentStrings` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683187(VS.85).aspx) is called. This function returns "a pointer to a block of memory that contains the environment variables *of the calling process* (both the system and the user environment variables)".

Accessing the environment block of another process is a bit more tricky. Oleksiy Gapotchenko has written an [excellent blog post](https://blog.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net/reading-environment-variables) and also provides a sample solution.

Comment: Quick note for anyone trying this that you cannot use this method to read the environment variables of a process that has exited. You'll get an exception saying "Unable to read PEB", most likely because the PEB structure of the process was cleared from memory after the process exited.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can find it looks like that's simply not an action supported out-of-the-box.

The closest thing is

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Unfortunately that seems to be "locked" to the current process. If there were just a way to set what process to target you'd be golden.

Fortunately, Microsoft provides a "reference source" you can use to see what the underlying code in .NET is (in this case http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,20e3d8aa4eb8f4b1). If the function supports doing what you want you could make your own wrapper for it.

If you trace that down you find a Win32 call in an unsafe context is ultimately responsible: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/c48702b7df790f4c.html

It looks like even that call is locked to the current process, so you'll need to write your own code for it. Here's an example in C (or C++, can't tell lol):
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25647/Read-Environment-Strings-of-Remote-Process

You can translate the gist of that into unsafe C# and do the same thing using DllImports, etc. as necessary.. Sorry the answer isn't that easy, but it sounds like a fun project to me!

Edit: Oh I love how the linked possible duplicate did the same research that I did, found the same things, heh.. Just know that I didn't just copy-paste, did the research myself..